# OpenJPA: several @Embedded vs one @ElementCollection

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I am trying to decide which annotation to use. Can you offer your opinion?

What I have now:

```
@Entity
public class Balance {
    @Embedded
    private Amount amountAtm;

    @Embedded
    private Amount amountBranch;

    @Embedded
    private Amount amountVault;
}

@Embeddable
public Amount {
    private BigDecimal debit;
    private BigDecimal credit;
}
```

What I want to change it to:

```
@Entity
public class Balance {
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<AmountType, Amount> amounts;
}

public enum AmountType {
    ATM, BRANCH, VAULT;
}
```

The Amount would stay the same.

The reason for this change, is because the amounts inside the balance are conceptually a collection. I either display/change all of them at the same time, or none at all. So, I treat them as a group.

Questions:

1. Right now the amounts are stored in the same table as the balances (I override column names, this is not shown in the code). However, if I make this change there is NO WAY I can store all this data in one table. I would have to store amounts in a separate table. **Is this correct?**
2. Considering that now I will have to make JOINs in SQL, etc. **How will this affect the performance?** Let's say I am using Oracle 11g and I have 100,000 balance records (and therefore 300,000 amounts). Will I notice the slowdown in the application after the change?

Comment: JPA (1 or 2 or 2.1) has no such @EmbeddedCollection annotation, and is not in the OpenJPA docs either. Perhaps clarify what you mean ...

Comment: @DataNucleus you are right, I meant \@ElementCollection annotation. also, i have rewrote the question completely to make it more clear. thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's correct.
2. Impossible to say without testing. I don't see how it could be faster than storing the six fields in the table directly.

What I don't understand is why you're not satisfied with your three fields. If you want to be able to have a `Map<AmountType, Amount> getAmounts()` method (and the corresponding setter) in your entity, nothing prevents you from adding it and implementing it yourself:

```
public Map<AmountType, Amount> getAmounts() {
    Map<AmountType, Amount> result = new HashMap<AmountType, Amount>(3);
    result.put(AmountType.ATM, amountAtm);
    result.put(AmountType.BRANCH, amountBranch);
    result.put(AmountType.VAULT, amountVault);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, JB. I wanted to be able to loop through these objects... Yes, I could implement the method like you described, but I was thinking that using @ElementCollection would be a cleaner solution and the "right way" to do it. I mean, if _conceptually_ these objects are a collection, isn't that reason enough to map them as such?

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. But then, they should also probably be in their own table as well.